# How to assign a group of users under a domain name to Security?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've been searching for solution from the internet, unfortunately there is none that works for me.

I needed to grant 'Browser' access to all users in the company, all users are under 'COMPANY' domain name.

I had tried to do this but the users still received insufficient permission .

Answer (score 0):

- Create a login on SQL server with all user on company domain.
- Grant exec permission on the table or sp that featch the data for the report.

Comment: Hi Hiten004. Thanks for your suggestion. Finally I found a solution and I would like to share it with everybody who needs it.

I added this in the security and it works like charm :)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users

Comment: Add security on SSRS or SQL server?